# CSV that contains blobs, to the actual files

Tags: csv, blob

I have extracted a load of files from a webapp, and all it gives me is a CSV file containing a load of blobs of the file, and the filename.

What is the best way to convert these to the actual files? I was thinking using a powershell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a PowerShell script, that extracts the blobs and filename from CSV and saves in a given directory as raw files.

```
$path = 'D:\TEMP\Attachments\extract.csv'
$exportPath = 'D:\TEMP\Files'

Import-Csv $path | Foreach-Object { 
    $b64 = $_.BODY
    $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($b64)
    $filename = $exportPath  + "\" + $_.NAME 
    [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, $bytes)
}
```